# How to add SearchView to Appbar that has a navigation menu?

Tags: java, android

I want to implement this design to my appbar: [App bar with menu and search bar etc](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xkYuv.png)

When the searchView is clicked it should look like this: [SearchView clicked](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kDPzz.png)

so far i have managed to create the app bar as below:
[Appbar with navigation menu and title](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Esxa0.png)

When menu is clicked:
[Expanded navigation menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/47GUh.png)

**The problem is every tutorial I seem to watch only has ONE menu.xml file for the app bar.**
My existing Menu.xml file is for showInNavigationView. I'm unsure where to add the searchView, the favourite and chat button.

**How and where do I add the SearchView and favourite etc icons?**
Any help at all is appreciated!

My files are as such:

Activity_Homepage.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> <androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".HomepageActivity">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
            android:id="@+id/appbarLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <com.google.android.material.appbar.MaterialToolbar
                android:id="@+id/topAppBar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:background="@color/white"
                app:navigationIcon="@drawable/baseline_menu_24"
                app:title="NewAPP">
            </com.google.android.material.appbar.MaterialToolbar>

        </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/frameLayout"
            android:layout_below="@+id/appbarLayout"/>

    </RelativeLayout>

    <com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/navigation_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header"
        app:menu="@menu/my_navigation_items"
        /> </androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

my_navigation_items.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:showIn="navigation_view">

<item android:title="Discover">
    <menu>
        <group android:checkableBehavior="single">
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_browsePost"
            android:icon="@drawable/outline_search_24"
            android:title="Browse Posts"/>

        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_createPost"
            android:icon="@drawable/outline_create_24"
            android:title="Create a Post"/>

        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_myCommunity"
            android:icon="@drawable/outline_people_alt_24"
            android:title="My Community"/>

        </group>
    </menu>
</item>

<item android:title="Personal">
    <menu>
        <group android:checkableBehavior="single">
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_myProfile"
            android:icon="@drawable/outline_person_24"
            android:title="My Profile"/>

        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_settings"
            android:icon="@drawable/outline_settings_24"
            android:title="Settings"/>
        </group>
    </menu>
</item>

<group android:checkableBehavior="single">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_logout"
        android:icon="@drawable/outline_logout_24"
        android:title="Log out"/>
</group>
```

nav_header.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/appName"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Give&amp;Take"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
        android:textSize="32dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
        android:fontFamily="@font/roboto_medium"/>

    <View
        android:layout_below="@+id/appName"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        style="@style/line"/>
    
</RelativeLayout>
```

Code in HomepageActivity.java:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_homepage);
    //SETTING DEFAULT FRAGMENT PAGE
    replaceFragment(new SettingsFragment()); //SET HOMEPAGE BROWSE POST FRAGMENT HERE AS DEFAULT

    mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

    MaterialToolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.topAppBar);
    DrawerLayout drawerLayout = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    NavigationView navigationView = findViewById(R.id.navigation_view);
    toolbar.setNavigationOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) { //menu button
            drawerLayout.openDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        }
    });

    //when click on any option in navigation view
    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(new NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
            int id = item.getItemId();
            item.setChecked(true);
            drawerLayout.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START); //close menu when any of the option is clicked
            switch(id){
                case R.id.nav_browsePost:
                    Toast.makeText(HomepageActivity.this, "BrowsePost is clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    break;
                case R.id.nav_createPost:
                    replaceFragment(new CreateAPostFragment());
                    Toast.makeText(HomepageActivity.this, "CreatePost is clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    sendUserToCreatePostActivity();

                    break;
                case R.id.nav_myCommunity:
                    Toast.makeText(HomepageActivity.this, "MyCommunity is clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    break;
                case R.id.nav_myProfile:
                    Toast.makeText(HomepageActivity.this, "MyProfile is clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    break;
                case R.id.nav_settings:
                    replaceFragment(new SettingsFragment());
                    Toast.makeText(HomepageActivity.this, "Settings is clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    break;
                case R.id.nav_logout:
                    mAuth.signOut();
                    Toast.makeText(HomepageActivity.this, "Logged out", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    sendUserToMainActivity();

                    break;
                default:
                    return true;
            }
            return true;
        }
    });
}
```